# Dual boot installation

Tags: dual-boot

I would like to install Ubuntu on a seperate harddrive to my Windows file system.
I have a harddrive installed in the computer that shall be used solely for a Linux system.
I thought I'd try to install with the Windows installer, but it can't see the Linux harddrive - probably because it's already had Linux on it before and Windows refuses to recognize it.
Although, Windows CAN see the harddrive in the device manager, it's not showing in "My Computer".

Do I have to download the full install CD, or is there a workaround for this so I can still use the Windows installer?

Answer (score 0):

I'd download the installer and use that to install to the drive - even if you use Wubi it will have to download what it needs anyway - so you'll not save much in the way fo bandwidth.

If you get it with a torrent then you will be sure the iso you get is good.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to install from the Live CD instead of WUBI. This way you will have the cleanest installation, and the best performance from Ubuntu. If you insist on installing from within WUBI, I 'm sure Windows can format a hard drive that was previously formatted with a Linux filesystem, probably through Administrative Tools -> Disk Management or something similar.